# How can I allow BitmapData.draw on an HDS video loaded via OSMF

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, osmf

I am loading [HDS video](http://www.adobe.com/products/hds-dynamic-streaming.html) (an .f4m file) using [OSMF](http://www.osmf.com) and want to draw the video to a `BitmapData`. I am currently getting the following error:

```
Exception fault: SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: [url ommitted] cannot access null. No policy files granted access.
```

If I were just using a plain `NetStream` I believe I could fix this by setting `.checkPolicyFile` to `true`.

Is this the case, and how can I achieve the same in OSMF?

Comment: So it's right to assume you do actually have a crossomain.xml file at the root directory of the domain where the data is being accessed?  Also are you running the swf on a server or locally?  If local have you added the path to the flash player trust settings?

Comment: Yes, I have a crossdomain up and I have tried local, same domain, etc. It turns out this has to do with the fact that HDS uses a 'data creation mode' NetStream. This involves calling ns.play(null) and then continues calls of ns.appendBytes(). This means the security model is checking to see if I have access to 'null' (which was passed to play), which apparently I do not. Very strange. I'm still looking into it...